# DB2 UPDATE stored proc looping through INPUT XML

Tags: xml, stored-procedures, cursor, db2, batch-processing

I'm new to DB2 and stored procedures. I want to write a stored procedure in DB2 which will update the table. The procedure has an XML document as its input parameter.

I need to loop through each record of XML, pick some nodes and update corresponding rows in table. This stored procedure will be used to batch update the table.

I have the pseudo code for procedure, but not sure how it will look in DB2.

The INPUT XML is of the FORMAT

```
<Root>
  <Record>
    <a>1234</a>
    <b>1</b>
    <c>2</c>
    <d>A</d>
    <e>B</e>
    <f>C</f>
  </Record>
<Record>
    <a>1235</a>
    <b>1</b>
    <c>2</c>
    <d>A</d>
    <e>B</e>
    <f>C</f>
  </Record>
</Root>
```

The procedure will be similar to

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_BATCH (IN INDOC XML)
P1: BEGIN

FOR rec AS rec CURSOR FOR(
SELECT 
Record.XMLQUERY('//Record/a/text()') AS A, 
Record.XMLQUERY('//Record/b/text()') AS B,
Record.XMLQUERY('//Record/c/text()') AS C,
Record.XMLQUERY('//Record/d/text()') AS D,
Record.XMLQUERY('//Record/e/text()') AS E,
Record.XMLQUERY('//Record/f/text()') AS F
FROM
TABLE (INDOC)Record--Not Sure how to construct table from input xml
)
DO
UPDATE XYZ.TEMP_TABLE
SET ACOL=Record.A,
BCOL=Record.B,
CCOL=Record.C,
DCOL=Record.D,
ECOL=Record.E
WHERE
FCOL=Record.F;
END FOR;
END P1
```

Please help me to create above procedure. I'm not able to get correct syntax for ForEach, XML node handling, CURSOR and LOOPING in DB2.

**ANSWER**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_BATCH(IN DOC XML)
BEGIN
MERGE INTO XYZ.TEMP_TABLE AS T
USING (SELECT X.* FROM 
XMLTABLE('$d/Root/Record' passing DOC as "d"
COLUMNS 
        "A" VARCHAR(10) PATH 'a',
        "B" VARCHAR(10) PATH 'b',
        "C" VARCHAR(10) PATH 'c',
        "D" VARCHAR(10) PATH 'd',
        "E" VARCHAR(10) PATH 'e',
        "F" VARCHAR(10) PATH 'f' 
) AS X) AS XT
ON T.FCOL=XT."F"
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET
T.ACOL=XT."A",
T.BCOL=XT."B",
T.COL=XT."C"
END
```

Comment: what's your db2 version?

Comment: I'm using DB2 Express-C 9.7.5

Comment: Thanks for showing the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Db2 has decent support for XML data, so you have a few options on how to shred XML and apply it to one or more tables.

The function you're looking for is [XMLTABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022195.html). It is by far the most flexible way to shred XML into a single tabular result set.

When your incoming XML document contains data that needs to go to multiple tables, the [DECOMPOSE XML DOCUMENT](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0022721.html) statement is powerful, but it requires a pre-registered XML Schema Document (XSD) containing special annotations that specify the relational target for each input XML node. Moreover, the `DECOMPOSE XML DOCUMENT` statement can only write to permanent tables and not to [declared global temporary table](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003272.html)s (DGTTs) which are often used for staging and adjusting data before it gets written to its final destination.

As for using a cursor to apply the shredded data, you could replace the entire loop with a single [MERGE](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html) statement that uses the result set from `XMLTABLE` as the input expression. There are lots of examples showing how to use Db2's `MERGE` statement for "upsert" processing, in which each incoming row may be applied by either an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE` depending on whether the specified key already exists in the destination table.

Comment: Thanks alot! I got it working as per your valuable suggestion.

Comment: To update 100 such xml records, sp takes around 1.5 minutes. I think it's too long..what could be the reasons?..

Comment: Ensure the target table is properly indexed for the updates you are performing, and that the table has accurate statistics (via RUNSTATS). DB2 has an explain utility that shows the access plan that the optimizer has chosen for a query. You will probably have an easier time using the explain utility on just the merge statement itself than on the entire stored procedure. The statement you run through the explain utility will benefit from a hardcoded XML document that contains valid data for the query.

Comment: Yes.You are right. Actually I was joining on part of composite primary key. When I used correct columns for join condition, the query worked perfectly. It takes now few milliseconds to update 100 rows. Thanks again!